# Java Cannot dequeue a message from Oracle AQ

Tags: weblogic, spring-jms, oracle-aq

I'm trying to deploy an application in weblogic which is based on a Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer. I have set up weblogic using a foreign server to provide access to the AQ connection factory and destination under JNDI names.

I have a simple message listener which logs the messages it receives (just a test), I wrap this message listener in a Spring DMLC shown below:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/aq/admAQCF"  />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="handlersDest"  jndi-name="jms/aq/dpqueue"/>

 <beans:bean id="testMessageListener" class="aquila.administrator.docprod.core.handler.adm.TestHandler"/>

 <beans:bean id="testMLC" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <beans:property name="destination" ref="handlersDest"/>
    <beans:property name="messageListener" ref="testMessageListener"/>
 </beans:bean>
```

Whenever I try deploy this application in weblogic I get the following exception from the DMLC:

```
testMLC-26 [Tue Mar 13 14:07:52 GMT 2012] AQjmsConsumer.jdbcDequeue: Exception: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-122: Internal error Corrupted message
oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-122: Internal error Corrupted message
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsError.throwEx(AQjmsError.java:334)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsUtil.getTextData(AQjmsUtil.java:751)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsTextMessage.readTextMessageContainer(AQjmsTextMessage.java:308)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsTextMessage.<init>(AQjmsTextMessage.java:148)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.jdbcDequeue(AQjmsConsumer.java:1389)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:1035)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:960)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:938)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receive(AQjmsConsumer.java:790)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:431)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:311)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this so that java can receive the messages on the queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this was to add "orai18n.jar" into the class path of whatever was actually attempting to dequeue from the message queue. In my example I added the jar to the classpath of the application server and that resolved the problem.

Comment: if you use ojdbc10 19.3.0.0 then you have to add same version number of orai18n  to pom